# Cannot change NavigationView icon size?

Tags: android-studio, svg, navigationview

I applied a custom style to my NavigationView like this:

```
app:theme="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"
```

In my styles.xml like this:

```
<style name="NavigationDrawerStyle">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">50dp</item>
    <item name="listPreferredItemHeightSmall">50dp</item>
</style>
```

However, the icons I am using do not change in size, regardless of the dp values I insert into the custom style. All it does is scale the space each item takes up, the space inbetween options increases etc., but the icon size is fixed. I cannot find any options/attributes to modify the icon size. How do I do that?

This is an example icon I am using:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="73dp"
    android:height="93dp"
    android:viewportWidth="73.79"
    android:viewportHeight="93.25">
<path
    android:pathData="M73.06,9.52 L36.9,0 0.74,9.52s-9,67.56 36.16,83.74C82.1,77.08 73.06,9.52 73.06,9.52Z"
    android:fillColor="#2980b9"/>
<path
    android:pathData="M36.9,0V93.25C-8.3,77.08 0.74,9.52 0.74,9.52Z"
    android:fillColor="#3498db"/>
<path
    android:pathData="M36.9,44.25m-25.69,0a25.69,25.69 0,1 1,51.38 0a25.69,25.69 0,1 1,-51.38 0"
    android:fillColor="#2c3e50"/>
<path
    android:pathData="M36.9,23a10,10 0,1 1,-10 10A10,10 0,0 1,36.9 23Z"
    android:fillColor="#ecf0f1"/>
<path
    android:pathData="M56.78,60.51a25.69,25.69 0,0 1,-39.77 0,21.31 21.31,0 0,1 39.77,0Z"
    android:fillColor="#ecf0f1"/>
</vector>
```

Edit: I would also like to be able to specify the height and width seperately, if that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

*I reformatted an example of the question author from android to svg, in order to try to explain the scaling principle.*

- In the example below, the icon has a fixed size

`width="73" height="93" viewBox="0 0 73 93"`

`width` and`height` is `viewport` - the area that we see on the display of the gadget.
The proportion of `viewport / viewBox` determines the scale of the icon image.

In our case, the scale will be `M1:1` That is, the icon will be shown, as is 73 x 93

When increasing the `viewport`, let's say twice `width = "146"` `height = "186"`
The proportion will be - `viewport / viewBox = 2` The icon image will also double.
The viewport display area in the example is a red frame.

An attempt to change the size of the icon through the container styles is indicated by the example of a green frame.

```html
<style>
#container-Green {
display:block;
width:146;
height:186; 
outline: 1px solid green;

}

</style>

<div id="container-Green"> 

<svg  width="73" height="93" viewBox="0 0 73 93" style="border:1px solid red;" >
   <g id="icon">
<path     d="M73.06,9.52 L36.9,0 0.74,9.52s-9,67.56 36.16,83.74C82.1,77.08 73.06,9.52 73.06,9.52Z"
    fill="#2980b9"/>
<path   d="M36.9,0V93.25C-8.3,77.08 0.74,9.52 0.74,9.52Z"
    fill="#3498db"/>
<path   d="M36.9,44.25m-25.69,0a25.69,25.69 0,1 1,51.38 0a25.69,25.69 0,1 1,-51.38 0"
    fill="#2c3e50"/>
<path
    d="M36.9,23a10,10 0,1 1,-10 10A10,10 0,0 1,36.9 23Z"
    fill="#ecf0f1"/>
<path
    d="M56.78,60.51a25.69,25.69 0,0 1,-39.77 0,21.31 21.31,0 0,1 39.77,0Z"
    fill="#ecf0f1"/> 
 </g>
</svg> 

</div>
```

**Conclusions:**

- You can not change the size of the icon by changing the parent
  container's dimension styles.
- Change the size of the icon is possible only when changing the size
  of `viewport` or`viewBox`
- For fixed values, the icon scale will not change when the browser
  window is resized. In other words, the image will not be responsive.

### Example with percentage values

```html
<style>
#container-Green {
display:block;
width:30%;
height:30%; 
outline: 1px solid green;

}

</style>

<div id="container-Green"> 

<svg  width="30%" height="30%" viewBox="0 0 73 93" style="border:1px solid red;" >
   <g id="icon">
<path     d="M73.06,9.52 L36.9,0 0.74,9.52s-9,67.56 36.16,83.74C82.1,77.08 73.06,9.52 73.06,9.52Z"
    fill="#2980b9"/>
<path   d="M36.9,0V93.25C-8.3,77.08 0.74,9.52 0.74,9.52Z"
    fill="#3498db"/>
<path   d="M36.9,44.25m-25.69,0a25.69,25.69 0,1 1,51.38 0a25.69,25.69 0,1 1,-51.38 0"
    fill="#2c3e50"/>
<path
    d="M36.9,23a10,10 0,1 1,-10 10A10,10 0,0 1,36.9 23Z"
    fill="#ecf0f1"/>
<path
    d="M56.78,60.51a25.69,25.69 0,0 1,-39.77 0,21.31 21.31,0 0,1 39.77,0Z"
    fill="#ecf0f1"/> 
 </g>
</svg> 

</div>
```

**Conclusions:**

- When setting the values of `viewport` as a percentage, the icon image
  is responsive.
- You can change the initial size of the icon by changing the
  percentage of the `viewport` or the percentage in the parent
  container.

*My favorite subject is svg, in androde I understand much worse.*
But after understanding how scaling works, you probably can reformat my example from svg to android.

Little did a search on the theme of percentage values in android:

Look, can help you:

```
<android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:background="#f0f0f0"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
        app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
        app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
        app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%" />
</android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>
```

In order to connect the library, add the dependency to the dependencies section of the `build.gradle` file of the application:

`compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.0.0'`

23.0.0 - the current latest version of the library, may change with time.

[More details on the use](http://www.androidauthority.com/using-the-android-percent-support-library-630715/)

Comment: That was my initial idea aswell. Though, when deleting those entries it gives me a rendering error and the app crashes. What's the syntax for %? I tried 100% with and without "" though both gave an error. Also you said specified for the viewport, though the code you implemented were the "standard" dimensions, not the viewport dimensions. Thus I am not quite sure what you meant exactly.

Comment: Also, I read on other threads that those values are just specified in the case of SDK versions below 21, where raster graphics are created and SVGs are not scaled. Even then, why is the icon in the Navigation View not the size 73x93dp? I would appreciate some additional info or a fully detailed answer on how you'd go about this. Just deleting the dim attributes like you said does nothing but return an error in my case.